# insert guardar todos los registros de una tabla en otra mas parametro fecha

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, insert

Quiero guardar todos los registros que contiene una "tabla A" 
en otra "tabla B" al presionar evento submith "botón guardar periodo actual

Actual mente mi pagina principal contiene ya 2 formularios y pensé que para evitar saturar mas mis tablas filtros y campos editables

decidí que preferiría un boton "link" que me guie a guardar_periodo.php
donde solo  se ejecute :

```
INSERT INTO tabla B SELECT * FROM tabla A
```

y me regrese al insertar la tabla con:

```
header("location: index.php");
```

Mi problema inicia en que adicional mente quiero agregar un valor adicional para un campo extra que tiene la "tabla B" que es periodo quien tiene que adjuntar la fecha de cuando fue agregado este registro

mi ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO tabla B (`nombre`,`email`,`current_time`)
SELECT * FROM `Tabla A`
```

pero creo que lo estoy haciendo mal:

```
<?php
include "conn.php";
// (variable con el querry = $conn )
INSERT INTO tabla B (`nombre`,`email`,`current_time`)
    SELECT * FROM `Tabla A`;

header("location: dashboard.php");
?>
```

podrian alguien indicarme en que lo estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dudo mucho que se pueda hacer de esa manera que pretendes hacerlo, ya que el resultado que devuelve la consulta es un array o json entonces solo en este caso le estarias pasando un parametro, por ende le falta ingresar datos...

```
<?php
include "conn.php";

//nota: creo que aqui le falta invocar el metodo query de la conexion (ya tu sabras como esta el metodo de conexcion y de ejecusion query

// aqui en la variable resultado se alamcenas los valores del resultado

$resultado= SELECT * FROM `Tabla A`;

INSERT INTO tabla B (`nombre`,`email`,`current_time`) VALUES ('$resultado[0]', '$resultado[1]', current_time());


header("location: dashboard.php");
?>
```

espero te sirva y la marques como solucion... By: JJ

Comment: hola, gran aporte y muchas gracias, e tratado de implementar tue jemplo agregando un or die para ver el error de por que no inserta la informacion pero me sale : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]El nombre de columna 'periodo' no es válido. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]El nombre de columna 'periodo' no es válido. ) )

Comment: lo que sucede es que estas tratando de insertar valor a una columna llamada "periodo" de la cual no existe en la tabla a la que estas haciendo referencia

Answer (score 0):

En principio si enumeras los campos del insert debes enumerar también los del select de la otra tabla, que han de tener el mismo nombre. En cuanto al campo nuevo, se me ocurre que puedes usar la fecha actual (formateada según tú campo fecha de destino) sacada del momento en que haces el select en la tabla A.

```
INSERT INTO tabla B (nombre, email, current_time)
    SELECT nombre, email, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS current_time FROM Tabla A
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Ademas de la repuesta anterior la cual le envias la fecha desde el servidor web, podrías usar la función getdate() propia de sql server, con lo cual le pondria la fecha actual del servidor de base de datos

```
$resultado= SELECT * FROM `Tabla A`;

INSERT INTO tabla B (`nombre`,`email`,`current_time`) VALUES ('$resultado[0]', '$resultado[1]', SELECT getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra posibilidad es la siguiente:

Crear la columna `current_time` de `tabla B` de tipo `TIMESTAMP`, indicando como valor por defecto `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` y poniéndole la restricción `NOT NULL`.

En el `CREATE TABLE`  sería:

```
... current_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

De ese modo te evitas estar manejando fechas y el manejador de base de datos se encargará de poner la marca temporal a cada registro cuando éste sea creado.

Si optas por esa posibilidad, la consulta de inserción podría ser así:

```
INSERT INTO `tabla B` (`nombre`,`email`)
    SELECT `nombre`,`email` FROM `Tabla A`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví y agrega un par de notas extra, agradezco enorme mente a los que respondieron y aun que no tuve tiempo de responder a todos si les tome encuentra.

Agrego como termino mi solución que es muy similar al de srJJ

```
<?php
include "../controler/conn.php";

$resultado= "SELECT * FROM `usuario` ";

$query = "INSERT INTO periodo ('nombre', 'email', 'periodo') SELECT nombre, email, current_time  FROM usuario";
sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die (print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

header("location: dashboard.php");
?>
```

Perdón por no responder antes pero me salió un error que impedía que me identificara los datos usando el primer ejemplo y quería que quedara bien antes de agradecer y colocar la solución implementandola en todos mis formularios.