# ¿Cómo obtener el reloj JavaScript del servidor?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, he creado un reloj en *JavaScript* que está en un `input`. Funciona bien, pero el problema es que obtiene la hora de la máquina del usuario y quisiera que la obtenga del servidor donde está alojada la aplicación.

Código del *script* del reloj:

```js
function mueveReloj(){

    momentoActual = new Date()
    dia = momentoActual.getDate()
    año = momentoActual.getFullYear()
    mes = momentoActual.getMonth() + 1
    hora = momentoActual.getHours()
    minuto = momentoActual.getMinutes()
    segundo = momentoActual.getSeconds()

     if (hora < 10 ){
      hora = "0" + hora
    }
     if (minuto < 10 ){
      minuto = "0" + minuto
    }
    if (segundo < 10 ){
      segundo = "0" + segundo
    }

    if (dia < 10 ){
      dia = "0" + dia
    }
     if (mes < 10 ){
      mes = "0" + mes
    }

    horaImprimible = año + "-" + mes + "-" + dia + " " + hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo

    document.getElementById('fechaout').value = horaImprimible

    timeout = setTimeout("mueveReloj()",1000)
}
```

```html
<body onload="mueveReloj()">
  <input disabled id="fechaout" />
</body>
```

Comment: La respuesta va a depender, por que del lado del servidor requerimos de un lenguaje que pueda ser interpretado ahi y tal vez con AJAX recuperarlo

Comment: yo utilizo php, como  tendría que hacer la consulta de la hora en el servidor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder obtener la hora del servidor, deberás seguir estos pasos:

**Paso 1**

En el servidor genera un archivo .php con el siguiente contenido:

**tuarchivo.php**

```
<?php

echo  date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

**Paso 2**

Como estás tratando de recuperar dicho valor en tu vista, deberás hacer uso de AJAX para pedir al servidor esa información; en este caso usaré la *API Fetch*

- Primero colocamos un `div` donde pintaremos la información que nos regresará la llamada al server

código

```
<input type="text" id="hora">
```

Finalmente:

- En nuestro .js vamos a establecer dentro de una función la llamada al archivo .php que tiene la info. requerida
- Formateamos como texto la data que proviene
- En el segundo `then` de nuestra promesa recuperamos el `input` por medio de su `id` y con `innerHTML` le asignamos `data` que proviene del servidor
- Como requerimos que la información se actualice de forma constante, entonces usamos `setInterval` para indicar que el primer argumento que es el nombre de la función anteriormente creada, se verá invocada cada segundo como lo indica el segundo argumento pasado

Código:

```
<script>
    let reloj = document.getElementById("hora")
    function muestraReloj () {
            fetch("tuarchivo.php")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => reloj.value = data)
    }
    setInterval(muestraReloj, 1000)
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Aprendiz, lo voy a probar y te luego te informo como me fue

Comment: Cualquier duda me avisas @Julio y con gusto te apoyo

Comment: Hola Aprendiz, .disculpa  no puedo insertar el valor de la fecha en el input text  que es id="fechaout"..

Comment: @Julio revisa la edición que haré

Comment: Muchas gracias Aprendiz, le agrege  timeout = setTimeout("muestraReloj()",1000) antes de cerrar la función porque despues  en otra funcion necesito que se detenga en ese momento  cuando hago click y hago clearTimeout(timeout); para congelarlo que opinas

Comment: Disculpa Aprendiz, desde muchas gracias  ...me permitis hacerte solo 2 preguntas por chat si es posible...

Comment: El chat como las preguntas son lugares públicos, si son relacionados a la publicación considera hacerlos en tu pregunta, en caso contrario dejalos en el chat

Comment: Me salvaste y te agradezco, solo era poder hacerte las preguntas por chat para no molestarte...pero desde ya te agradezco

Comment: Como puedo obtener el valor del reloj lo e intentado con val con jquery con value de javascript pero nada.. yo genero la fecha después de un clic... gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Otra posibilidad sería mediante el uso de la librería [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) que es todo un referente para trabajar con tiempos en Javascript, por la facilidad con que podemos formatear y manejar las fechas<sup>1</sup>.

Desde el servidor puedes programar código que te devuelva una marca del tiempo (timestamp)  del momento actual, y con moment conviertes esa marca del tiempo en el formato que desees.

Desde el cliente haces una petición cada un segundo (o un minuto si no interesa mostrar los segundos) y actualizas el contenedor que muestra la fecha y la hora.

### Código PHP

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$fecha = new DateTime();
echo json_encode(array("timeStamp"=>$fecha->getTimestamp()));
```

Este código devuelve un JSON con una clave `timeStamp` que contiene la marca del tiempo del servidor.

```
{"timeStamp":1584218642}
```

### Javascript

```js
const url = 'http://main.xfiddle.com/code_65721226.php';
var elDateTime = document.getElementById('dateTime');
lauchTimer();

function lauchTimer() {
  setInterval(async function() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    moment.locale('es');
    var dateString = moment.unix(json.timeStamp).format("DD MMMM YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    elDateTime.textContent = dateString;
    console.log(dateString);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<p id="dateTime"></p>
```

Comment: A. Cedano la respuesta que das es mas compleja para mi, si edito mi respuesta que fue la que me dio Aprendiz creo que obtengo lo mismo

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta y voy a estudiarla...es otra forma de resolverlo pero el objetivo es que los usuarios de la aplicación no  puedan manipular fechas, si tomo la del terminal que usan ellos pueden manipularla, en cambio la del servidor por mas que cambien la fecha en su PC no cambian la fecha y hora del registro en la BD. A ud. que le parece?

Comment: @Julio si es para tener una marca del tiempo en un registro de la base de datos no necesitas hacer nada de esto, sino simplemente declarar una columna en la tabla del tipo TIMESTAMP  y darle por defecto el valor de CURRENT TIMESTAMP. De ese modo, cuando se cree una nueva fila en esa tabla esa columna adquirirá la marca del tiempo del momento en que fue creada.

Comment: A.Cedano, gracias!! es decir que ese campo seria automático, y solo tengo que insertar  los otros campos? Como si fuera autonumérico pero del tipo DATETIME y con la fecha del servidor donde se encuentra la BD?

Comment: @Julio es correcto, sería un campo de tipo `TIMESTAMP` o `DATETIME` pero para que ese campo tome el momento actual al crear la fila, en la definición de la tabla tendrias que ponerle un **`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`** [en el caso de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html). La sintaxis podría variar en otros manejadores de base de datos. Haciendo eso, todo ocurre de forma automática.

Comment: A.Cedano.  Excelente, y  muchas gracias por tu ayuda voy a investigar y probar como queda el código...

Comment: De nada @Julio aquí estamos para ayudarnos. [Aquí hay una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/181790/29967) donde explico un poco con detalle cómo funciona.

Answer (score 0):

En *PHP* se puede usar `time` para obtener el *timestamp*:

```
echo time();
```

En *JavaScript* se descarga el *timestamp* y se le pone un `+` a la izquierda para transformar el texto a número, de manera que se pueda aumentar la cantidad de segundos:

```
var pedido = new XMLHttpRequest()
pedido.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(descarga.readyState==4 && descarga.status==200){
    timestamp_descargado = +pedido.responseText
  }
}
pedido.open("GET","index.php")
pedido.send()
```

Ahora en `mueveReloj` simplemente se va aumentando de a 1 segundo, `++timestamp_descargado` cada vez que se llama al `setInterval`, de manera que no tenga que estar llamando al servidor a cada rato.

```
var momentoActual = new Date(timestamp_descargado)
++timestamp_descargado
```

Nota: Las variables en *JavaScript* deben declararse, puede ser con `var` o `let`, en mi caso prefiero `var` ya que permite una redeclaración en caso que se requiera.