# Obtener hora del servidor PHP, JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

tengo una intranet con información y un reloj control donde marco la hora de ingreso y salida y eso en base a la hora del servidor y en la pagina tengo un reloj pero que toma la hora del pc. **y necesito que muestre la hora del servidor**,
Me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar con respecto a eso, e realizado algunos intentos pero no logro llegar a la solución.
Estoy trabajando con wamp con php 5.6 y my SQL 5.7 y la pagina esta con Codeigniter como Framwork.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  function inicio(){
  var d = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
       toString(d);  
       document.miFormulario.f1t1.value = d;
       window.onload = inicio;
   }
  setInterval(inicio, 100);
 });
</script>

    <form name="miFormulario" action="mailto:promocion@guiarte.com" enctype="text/plain"> 
        <input type="text" name="f1t1" id="f1t1">
    </form>
```

en la sigiente imagen se puede aprciar que las horas que se muesran son distintas ya qe toman la hora del pc local y necesito que sea la hora del servidor para que sea la misma para todos los que ingresarn.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cuál es la duda?

Comment: explicate mejor, no comprendo que quieres hacer...

Comment: quieres obtener la hora del pc usuario(js) ó hora del servidor(php)?

Comment: Responde esto a tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336973/cómo-obtener-el-reloj-javascript-del-servidor/336976?r=SearchResults#336976 ?

Comment: ahí lo edite pero necesito que muestre la hora del servidor, y así todos vean los mismos datos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo obtener el reloj JavaScript del servidor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336973/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-reloj-javascript-del-servidor)

Comment: @BetaM me funciona a medias, es un poco lo que tenia pero desde distintos pc da distintas horas, al parecer toma la hora de los pc locales y no del servidor, y necesito que en el reloj vean todos la misma hora.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso te recomiendo que uses la libreria Moment.js podes usar timezones.
https://momentjs.com/
Ademas te permite formatear fechas y hacer operaciones formateadas con fechas.

```
//Ejemplo:
```

```js
const seoul = moment(new Date()).tz('Asia/Seoul');
const ny = moment(new Date()).tz('America/New_York');
console.log(seoul.toString());
console.log(ny.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

si estas trabajando con php lo mas fácil que puedes hacer es lo siguiente, dentro de tu documento html creas un script que contenga una variable llamada `serverDate` y esta variable sera igual a un script de php que contenga la fecha y hora del servidor podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```html
<script>
  var serverDate = "<?= $date(d-m-Y H:m:i) ?>";
</script>
```

de esta manera puedes usar la variable dateServer donde lo necesites y esta variable contendrá la hora del servidor.

espero te sea de ayuda